# Composition in Laravel 5.2? Possible? Recommended?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm about to start a Laravel project and I have doubts about how I should go about it. First of all, I'll have two types of users, the common user, and the admin. I have searched a bit and found out that having two tables is the best solution in my case. Because common users will have all the columns the admins have plus a few more.

I'll create a `users_table` and a `common_users_table`. The admins will have their data on the `users_table` and the common users will have their data spread across both of the tables, with a foreign key on the `common_users_table` referencing the `users_table`. This way no columns will be unused.

My problem is, I'm not sure how to accomplish that in Laravel. Should I create only 1 model? Maybe 2 models with a hasOne and belongsTo relationship? But when I make the registration forms, how will I register 2 models at once? What about authentication? There are so many things that I simply don't have the experience in Laravel to determine what is better in the long run.

So, if you are more experienced in Laravel and/or have faced a problem like this before, what is the best way to tackle this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Having two tables is _not_ the best solution. What happens if you need to add moderators? Are you going to create a _third_ table? Just have a `users` table with a `user_type` column. Then apply middleware to routes/controllers to restrict access to specific user types.

Comment: Agreed with @MartinBean, use one table, and make any columns that are not used by both user types nullable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into something like laravel's ACL and the Guards, as this would be a good thing to do: [ACL in Laravel](https://laracasts.com/search?q=ACL&q-where=lessons), so this would give you users and permissions,

There are also some nice little packages you could leverage.

Sorry, the link above you might need a subscription to watch, but the terms might be a good starter as well as the site for also help on the ACL stuff